# How to pass numbers in an array into a SQL statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am attempting to do a SQL query where I need to provide a lot of user id's.

Currently what I am trying to do is this:

```
following_ids = $redis.smembers(self.redis_key(:following))
Medium.includes([{comments: :user}, :likes, :user]).where("user_id IN (#{ following_ids.each { |id| id } }) OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
```

Now the `following_ids` is in this form: `["1", "2", "3"]`, containing user id's

But the loop I try to do seems to still put the whole array into the SQL statement. I can see this from my server log:

```
Medium Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "media".* FROM "media" WHERE (user_id IN (["2", "3"]) OR user_id = 1)
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: SELECT "media".* FROM "media" WHERE (user_id IN (["2", "3"])...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You want it to be in the form `("1", "2", "3")`?

Comment: Yes. It should look something like this: IN (id1, id2, id3... idx), so without the [] brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the interpolated code to:

`following_ids.to_s.tr("[]", "")`

So in total:

`Medium.includes([{comments: :user}, :likes, :user]).where("user_id IN ( #{following_ids.to_s.tr("[]", "") }) OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)`

UPDATE: See Kaspar's comment below for the preferred 'active record way' to do this.

Comment: Seems to work well, meanwhile found out that this is possible too actually: `Medium.includes([{comments: :user}, :likes, :user]).where("user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ?", following_ids, id)`. Will see which one I shall use. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Kaspar Oh yeah totally. That is actually the preferred way to do it! I should have thought of that. Will edit my answer to refer to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to complicate things that much. You could simply do

```
user_ids = $redis.smembers(self.redis_key(:following)) << id
Medium.includes([{comments: :user}, :likes, :user]).where(user_id: user_ids)
```

Comment: That is an even better approach. Thank you!